# Почему в рекурсивной функции используется параметр item?

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

```
def look_for_key(box):
    for item in box:
        if item == 'box':
            look_for_key(item)  # вот тут
        elif item == 'key':
            print(f'the key was found in the {box.index(item)+1} box')
```

Comment: Этот код явно сломан. Вложенный вызов `look_for_key(item)` не приводит ни к каким действиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `item` используется там, чтобы вызвать функцию `look_for_key()` с параметром равным "box". Фактически в данной ситуации запись `look_for_key(item)` эквивалентна записи `look_for_key("box")`, т.к. эта строчка выполняетс только тогда, когда значение `item` равно `"box"`.

Почему так сделано - ну фиг его знает, сложно сказать, не видя всего остального кода.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто переменная, которую так назвали, можете хоть что туда написать, даже "abraktabra" - и будет работать.

Человек, который писал код, предполагал, что box состоит из элементов каких-то (либо ключи словаря, либо элементы списка, множества, строки и т.п., во-общем, какое-то перечисляемое значение) И вот то, из чего состоит **box** - это и передается в функцию, которая что-то возвращает.

Comment: если написать туда "абракадарбра", то будет совсем другой результат

Comment: @Эникейщик, дополнил.